# Passar valor para service factory em angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, angularjs-services

Preciso passar dois valores (página e total) de $scope que estão no controller para um service factory, como faço? Existe alguma boa prática para fazer isso?

Service:

```
angular.module("myapp").factory("AtividadesAPI", function ($http, config) {

    var _getAtividades = function () {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/atividades");
    };

    var _getAtividadesPaginadas = function () {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/atividades?pagina=param1&total=param2");
    };

    return {
        getAtividades: _getAtividades,
        getAtividades: _getAtividadesPaginadas
    };

});
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Controller:

```
carregarAtividades = function () {
    AtividadesAPI.getAtividades().success(function (data) {
        $scope.atividades = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Como está o seu controller?

Comment: Atualizei com o controller, @CelsomTrindade. Era só passar como parâmetro mesmo, não sei como não pensei nisso.

Comment: Sim. Um dos modos é passar como parâmetro. Você pode fazer uma referência também. Assim, você atualiza no controller e ele automaticamente atualiza na factory, sem necessidade de passar parâmetro. Se tiver interesse, posso elaborar uma outra resposta abordando esse método =D

Comment: Opa, tenho sim. É sempre bom aprender outras formas de implementar, e vai complementar a resposta também.

Comment: Respondido Fernando! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente passa-los como parâmetro para a função que você criou. Paramêtros servem pra isso mesmo e você pode confirmar aqui [Angular Styleguide - Factories](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#factories).

```
angular.module("myapp").factory("AtividadesAPI", function ($http, config) {

    var _getAtividades = function () {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/atividades");
    };

    var _getAtividadesPaginadas = function (pagina, total) {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/atividades?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total);
    };

    return {
        getAtividades: _getAtividades,
        getAtividadesPaginadas: _getAtividadesPaginadas
    };

});
```

Seu controller fará a chamada:

```
AtividadesAPI.getAtividadesPaginadas($scope.pagina, $scope.total);
```

Answer (score 3):

Como conversado nos comentários, apesar de já haver uma resposta aceita, ela mostra apenas um modo de atualizar um dado na factory. Outro método, e talvez uma das melhores features do AngularJs, é atualizar os dados por referência, ou seja, ao invés de chamar uma função que atualize os dados, você cria um escopo com referência a um objeto na factory.

Assim, quando houver uma atualização, seja em controller, directive, component, etc.. O valor na factory também será atualizado.

Mas, para que isso funcione, você deve seguir uma regra básica: Todo valor a ser referenciado deve ser definido dentro da factory. Veja este exemplo:

```
angular.module(appModule)
.factory('empresaFactory', function() {
    //Factory
    const empresa = {}; //Esse objeto é apenas uma referência geral da factory, para que você acesse os dados ou funções;


    // Aqui declaramos os dados
    empresa.dados    = {}; //Dados da empresa
    empresa.produtos = []; //Lista de produtos da empresa


    // Aqui declaramos as funções
    /**
     * Função para atualizar os dados (declarados acima) após obter o endpoint de sua api
     */
    empresa.atualizaEmpresa= function(campo, valor) {
        return angular.extend(empresa[campo], valor); //Não sei se é extremamente necessário utilizar o extend, mas quando eu não utilizo desse modo, o comportamento é irregular
    }
    
    // Retornamos a factory
    return empresa;
})
```

Como você pode ver, eu criei 2 referências `(object) empresa.dados` e `(array) empresa.produtos` onde iremos armazenar os dados. Assim que você obter os dados, por exemplo, carregou os dados da empresa do banco de dados, você chama a função `empresa.atualizaDados` para criar o objeto inicial, assim:

**controller**

```
$scope.empresa = empresaFactory.dados; //Cria a referência

empresaFactory.atualizaEmpresa('dados', $scope.dadosDaEmpresa); //Semelhante a primeira respota

//Ou deste modo
$scope.empresa = dadosDaApi; //dados obtidos do seu banco de dados

//Ou atualizar apenas um valor
$scope.empresa.nome = 'Novo nome da empresa';
$scope.empresa.cnpj = '11.222.333/0000-99';
```

A mesma coisa serve para a array, você pode fazer toda a manipulação, veja:

**controller**

```
$scope.produtos = empresaFactory.produtos;

$scope.produtos.push(novoProduto); //Adiciona um produto
$scope.produtos.splice(index, 1); //Remove um produto
```

Todas essas atualizações que mencionei, elas vão refletir o resultado diretamente na "fonte", ou seja, na Factory, sem necessidade de chamar a atualização manualmente.

---

#### Importante!!!

Note que ainda assim eu chamo uma atualização manual na Factory com isso: `empresaFactory.atualizaEmpresa('dados', $scope.dadosDaEmpresa);`. **Eu**, particularmente, faço isso pois quando eu obtenho os dados iniciais, eles são feitos dentro do resolve do meu state, então é apenas um modo mais prático, pois eu não preciso criar uma referência somente para atualizar. Eu apenas atualizo direto como parâmetro.

Mas isso fica a seu critério.

Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar de modo claro e que você aprenda mais sobre isso. Esse método vai lhe ajudar se você tiver uma aplicação complexa com compartilhamento de dados em muitos locais.

Comment: Vou dar +1 pelas explicações ^^

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isto te ajuda:

```
$http.get({
    url: config.baseUrl + '/atividades', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {pagina: param1, total: param2}
 })
```

Aqui mostra outras possibilidades e tipos de argumentos que se pode passar no `$http.get`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: O que você está fazendo é um serviço http e não uma comunicação entre controller e factory.