# Como compartilhar a variável $scope de um controlador para outro com parâmetros em AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho isto:

```
$scope.products = [];

    $http.get('app/components/job/controller/teste.json').success(function (resource) {
        $scope.products  = resource;
});

$scope.getIdJobs = function(getIdJobs) {
    var result = $filter('filter')( $scope.products, {id:getIdJobs})[0];
    console.log(result);
    console.log(getIdJobs);
}
```

Pretendia que o meu segundo controlador conseguisse obter a variavel $scope.getIdJobs e guardar numa variável novamente.
Como posso fazer isso?

```
app.controller("job_detail", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$route","$rootScope", "$routeParams", function($scope, $http, $location, $route, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

    //image home
    $rootScope.home = false;

    //change color background in page job
    $scope.isOnCertainPage = function() {
        return $location.path() === "/job";
    };


    $http.get('app/components/job/controller/teste.json').success(function (resource) {
        $scope.products = resource;
        $scope.jobId = $routeParams.jobId;
        //console.log($scope.jobId);
    }); 

    console.log($scope.title, $scope.localidade, $scope.products);

}]);
```

app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl: "app/components/home/views/job_offers.html",
            controller: "employerCtrl"
        })
        .when("/job" , {
            templateUrl: "app/components/job/views/job.html",
            controller: "job"
        })
        .when("/job/:jobId" , {
            templateUrl: "app/components/job/views/jobdetail.html",
            controller: "job_detail" 
        })   
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });


});
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers

Comment: é um bom exemplo mas como estou a usar parametros em páginas diferentes ele perde-se a meio

Comment: Como assim? A sua dúvida era compartilhar uma variavel entre controladores, então há mais coisas pelo meio? Se sim, altere a sua pergunta e adicione essa informação.

Comment: ja alterei o conteúdo

Comment: Ainda não consigo entender o pretendido. Olhando para o link que o @Miguel compartilhou e a sua dúvida, ele resolve o problema. O que você entende no seu código como sendo parâmetro? Onde está esse parâmetro?

Comment: Considero um parâmetro por exemplo na minha app.js. Tenho o job e job/:id e ao ir para a página id vai com um parâmetro. Quero que a informação que carrego num tópico qualquer vá para a página correspondente desse ID

Comment: Então, no seu controlador `job_detail` você pode capturar o ID (jobId) e utiliza-lo no seu controlador. Não seria isso o pretendido?

Comment: Já consegui fazer com que o controlador envie a informação para outro controlador com o exemplo do Miguel. Eu estou a usar uma tecnologia do angularjs ng-click quando carregas no botão ele guarda numa variável. É possivel que essa variável quando carrega guardes na variavel que criei agora para poder enviar para o 2 controlador?

Comment: Leia a minha resposta nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164782/passar-valor-para-service-factory-em-angularjs

Comment: Você já pensou em utilizar ui-router para controlar a troca de página e assim receber parâmetros pela URL?

Answer (score 2):

Sou iniciante também mas vou tentar te ajudar dando duas dicas:

1. Existe `$localStorage` que guarda informações e quando carregado pode ser passada de controllers em controllers, muito usado para IDs.
2. Outra forma seria você armazenar esse `$scope.getIdJobs` em um serviço e depois utiliza-lo em outro controllers chamando-o: `job_detail.get();`

Comment: Tinha a ver com isso como o miguel disse em cima obrigado. Agora falta fazer com que a variável que criei guarde a informação da variável do ng-click e fica resolvido. Sabes se isso é possivel?

Comment: O $localStorage não é nativo do angular,  os módulos podem ser baixados aqui: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

O método 2, é o que descrevo na minha proposta de resposta. 
O jeito certo é o que funciona, mas existe o jeito recomendado também rsrsrs

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução simples é você ter uma factory que retorna o valor que vc precisa (um objeto por exemplo):
JS:

```
// Inicializa a aplicação
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Cria a factory para acompartilhar o valor da variável
myApp.factory('Fact', function(){
  return { Value: 'Foo' };
});

// 2 Controllers utilizando o mesmo valor
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Fact ){
  $scope.Alpha = Value;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Fact ){
  $scope.Beta = Value;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="Alpha.Value">
    First {{Alpha.Value}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="Beta.Value">
    Second {{Beta.Value}}
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/o3751yt3/

Quando aplicativos ficam maiores, mais complexos e mais difíceis de testar você pode não deseja expor todo o objeto de uma factory desta maneira, mas em vez disso, dar acesso limitado por exemplo via getters e setters:

```
myApp.service('Data', function(){
var data =
    {
        Value: ''
    };

    return {
        getValue: function () {
            return data.Value;
        },
        setValue: function (Value) {
            data.Value = Value;
        }
    };
});
```

Com esta abordagem os controllers consomem o service com novos valores e utiliza o $watch para observar as alterações :

```
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ) {

    $scope.Value = '';

    $scope.$watch('Value', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) Data.setValue(newValue);
    });
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){

    $scope.$watch(function () { return Data.getValue(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) $scope.Value = newValue;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Value">
        <br>Controller 1 : <strong>{{Value}}</strong>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        Controller 2: {{Value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/b6ekb3om/

Comment: Resposta super útil! Gostei muito e não sabia usar o $watch. Estou terminando meu aplicativo e isso pode mudar muito as coisas.

Comment: o $watch é um recurso muito bom de comunicação entre os componentes do angularjs, o uso excessivo não é recomendado pois ele ativa uma série de processos que podem elevar o consumo de recursos da sua aplicação. Use com moderação.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a variável products no $rootScope, assim você pode acessar ela pelo $rootScope em qualquer lugar.
Mas eu te aconselho a usar o ui-router para fazer a passagem de parâmetros, fica mais coeso e com menor chances de você ter problemas de substituição indesejável de valor de variável, ou algo do tipo.

Você deve definir o parâmetro no seu state:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    params: {
        param1: null
    },
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
```

E vai passa-lo dessa maneira:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({param1: value1})">View Contacts</a>

$state.go('contacts', {param1: value1})
```

Comment: Não é uma boa prática ficar clocando valores no $rootScope, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35346083

Comment: Foi o que eu disse @LeonanCarvalho, apenas leia com atencao: "Você pode colocar a variável products no $rootScope", "Mas eu te aconselho a usar o ui-router para fazer a passagem de parâmetros". Poder voce pode, mas eu aconselhei outra saida.

Answer (score 0):

Boas,

No meu entender o aconselhável é criares uma `factory` para a data, que será um `Objecto`, onde podes encapsular a data e respectivos `métodos`.
Depois é só chamar as `propriedades` que necessitares nos controllers.

Está aqui o exemplo neste [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11897/)

```
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
 return {
  data:[{id:1,content:''},{id:2,content:''},{id:3,content:''}, {id:4,content:''},{id:5,content:''},{id:6,content:'Restante Objecto...'},{id:7,content:''},{id:8,content:''},{id:9,content:''},{id:10,content:''}],
  result:{},
  filterById:function(id){

    //Estou a dar declarar o THIS numa variavel porque vou usa-lo dentro do forEach
    var that = this;

    that.data.forEach(function(item){
      if(item.id===id){that.result=item;}
    });
  }
 };
});
```

No controller que acessa ao `routerParams` chamas o método `filterById()`.

```
function FirstCtrl($scope,myService) {
  var RouterParamsId = 6;
  myService.filterById(RouterParamsId);
  $scope.job = myService.result;
  console.log()
}
```

No segundo controller é só declarar o `result` ou se necessário até podes filtrar novamente com um novo id.

```
function SecondCtrl($scope,myService) {
  $scope.job = myService.result;
}
```

Desta forma limpas os `controllers`, e tudo o que for relativo a essa data pode ser alcançado nos `controllers` e `directives` fácilmente.

Ou terás a opção do `$rootScope`, que também funciona para o que pretendes.

Acerca dos routers, aconselho-te a dares uma olhadela ao **ui-router**, uma ferramenta muito superior no meu entender.